# Embedding a mapsengine map into a website, also with a search bar

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to embed a map onto a website, without using the iframe provided when 'embed map' is selected from https://mapsengine.google.com

I just need it to have all of my custom locations on, together with their added information (address, opening hours, website etc.), and also a search bar should be included to search for a location.

I tried to add the search bar with https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox, 
But this doesn't seem to work with custom maps.

Comment: Use a [Maps Engine Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers)

Comment: @Dr.Molle I can't use that to put a search box on can I? I've got the points all imported fine: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/2/edit?hl=en&authuser=2&mid=zfUucyz9ZIEg.k9f_jxXISHYE

Comment: Why can't you? All the points will also be there when you use the layer